Can next-video just read from the remote source string?
Let me know if this completely defeats the purpose of next-video, but I've been given a requirement to get the video from one of our servers through a remote URL.
I know about the docs for remote strings through this: https://next-video.dev/docs#remote-videos
And as the docs say, in doing so will have the video process and be uploaded to my hosting provider (I'm using Vercel Blob).
It does feel very weird to have the videos saved on a server to be reuploaded to another server so I was wondering if it's possible to just read from the source string or if that just defeats the purpose of using next-video and I should consider another video player.
I'm running into this issue where if I don't have the JSON for the video, it won't play (since that's how next-video works). For some context, I'm going to be uploading videos to this server, and updating my database with video links, and my website will get the source string but from the database. But in order for me to have the video play, I have to get this to upload on my local first, but I can't always do that because maybe there will be 100 videos added. Is there a workaround for this or something I'm misunderstanding?
Does anyone have any other recommendations for video players for React/Next that help optimize the videos?
Thank you!
